# Etymology and Meaning of "geodeter"

Tags: meaning, etymology

While researching the source and use of mathematical formulas to calculate the radius of the earth, I came across this passage:

> Mitchell also showed that the mean radius of the earth was defined by
>   the ancient **geodeters** as being the meridian circumference divided by
>   44/7...

Online dictionary resources held no reference to the word **geodeter**. Using Google returned 4 indexed page results that contained an exact match, but the original language of each page is Swedish.

Is **geodeter** an actual word? If so, what is the meaning and etymology of the word?

[Source passage](https://books.google.com/books?id=efc_gR1QM-oC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=mean+radius+of+earth+in+miles&source=bl&ots=yTwHLRtT1A&sig=K_sQ0BG3O1EQbD7XmuYMigSkWAE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhr_7k9uPLAhUW-GMKHQh8BU0Q6AEIZjAL#v=onepage&q=mean%20radius%20of%20earth%20in%20miles&f=false)

Comment: [*A good example is provided by Puissant, a distinguished **geodeter** and cartographer*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dHe00X4MDKMC&pg=PA261&dq=%22geodeter%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22geodeter%22&f=false). But many if not most instances of the word in Google Books are actually misclassified *German* texts, so make of that what you will.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary doesn't list *geodeter,* but it does have the similar word *geodesist.*

Comment: "Using Google returned 4 indexed page results". In the UK, Google gives 3800 hits, mostly in Swedish, including a Wikipedia "category" page, dictionary entries, etc. The Swedish-English dictionary http://www.dict.com/?t=se&set=_ense&w=geodeter gives the root word "geodet" = "geodesist, surveyor"

Comment: @alephzero 4 indexed page results with an exact word match. i should have clarified the difference. i'll edit the post. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct term is ***[geodesist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/geodesy) not geodeter*** (M-W) from geodesy:

***Geodesy (n.) :***

> - 1560s, "the art of land surveying," from Modern Latin geodaesia, ***from Greek geodaisia "division of the earth;"*** ultimately from ge "earth" (see Gaia) + stem of daiein "to divide," from PIE *dai-, extended form of root *da- "to divide."
> - ***In modern use it refers to mathematical calculations derived from measuring large portions of the earth's surface. In this sense, in reference to structures, from 1936.***

Etymonline

See also [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=geodesist%2C%20geodesy%2C%20geodeter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgeodesist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgeodesy%3B%2Cc0): geodesy, geodesist, geodeter.

Comment: I think it might be worth adding a link from [NOAA](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/geodesist.html).

Answer (score 0):

From NOAA's article *[What Is Geodesy?](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/geodesy.html)*

> ### Geodesy
>
> The science of accurately measuring and understanding three fundamental properties of the Earth: its geometric shape, its orientation in space, and its gravity field— as well as the changes of these properties with time.

So *geodeters* are those people who practice *geodesy*: literally they who *measure the Earth*.